# Django count all occurances of one model in many other models

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

I'm using django and I have model names `Tags`.

It is used in 15 different models accros my entire application as ManyToManyField.

I need to get a `len` / `count` of all occurances of specific tag.

How am I suposed to do that ? Do I have to use Aggregate / annotate ? Select related ? Or something completelty different. Ofcourse using forloops is not an opiton.

Comment: Why for loop is not an option? It looks to me like you can simply do 15 count queries. What's your db?

Comment: My DB is Postgres. I have triend aggregate but I think is not for my needs. Because my website already have a lot of entries, and making a lot of queries is just bad, for now and for future. And I tried forloop but it's way to slow.

Comment: @SebastianBurzyński Well, you are logically doing multiple count queries over multiple tables. I don't see a room for real optimization here (i.e. IMHO any query will have similar execution time) except for proper indexing (but I assume you've already did that). Unless the data does not have to be in real time. Then you can periodically aggregate it and store it in a seperate table (e.g. materialized views if you are using PostgreSQL version something something).

Comment: @freakish Yes, I was thinking about that, I could write a celery task which would one a day at night check the occurances. But is that really a good aproach ? I guess it would be better than hitting to DB every request

Comment: @SebastianBurzyński Yes, it's a proper approach. If you really have this much data then you should do it.

Comment: @freakish ok, I guess I`ll go with that way then. Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

If you want be able to query in one request how many items are related to a Tag if they are different Django model, you should use the contenttypes framework provided by Django and not define Tags as a ManyToMany field.

Samples in the documentation is exactly what you want.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations